# Python 3 | Sorted, Max, Min Dictionary trought a ZIP, Error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning python 3 and I'm trying to use zip to transform a dictionary into a zip, this way I would be able to use functions like sorted, max and min on it.

Stocks is the dictionary btw.
So I tested it out like this, and it worked:

```
print(min(zip(Stocks.values(),Stocks.keys())))
print(max(zip(Stocks.values(),Stocks.keys())))
print(sorted(zip(Stocks.values(),Stocks.keys())))
```

Then I tried to do this:

```
stock_zip = zip(Stocks.values(), Stocks.keys())
print(max(stock_zip))
print(min(stock_zip))
print(sorted(stock_zip))
```

And this was the console result but I'm rather confused why it happened:

```
(520, 'GOOG')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "----------------------------------------------------------------", line 11, in <module>
    print(min(stock_zip))
ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
```

If anyone can explain me why the second piece of code doens't work I would be very appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python3.X `zip` returns an iterator, and once you pass it to a function actually you've consumed it, therefor when you pass it to another function you're passing an empty iterator.

```
In [15]: a = zip(range(3), range(3))

In [16]: list(a)
Out[16]: [(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)]

In [17]: list(a)
Out[17]: []
```

Answer (score 1):

`zip` returns an iterator.

When you are calling `max(stock_zip)` it iterates and consume the `stock_zip` iterator. By the time `min(stock_zip)` is called, `stock_zip` is totally consumed and is empty.

Instead of saving a reference to the output of `zip(dict.keys(), dict.values())` you can simply use `dict.items()`:

```
print(max(Stocks.items()))
print(min(Stocks.items()))
```

Comment: The problem in your solution is that in my Stocks dictionary, the keys are strings and the values are integers, I'm trying to organize the dictionary in terms of numbers not alphabetical order

Comment: @Fargo `Stocks.items()` is completely equivalent to `zip(Stocks.keys(), Stocks.values())`. You are trying to sort a dictionary but dictionaries don't even have a sense of order.

Comment: They are not equivalent, that can be demonstraded when I run  print(max(Stocks.items())) and it orders it by alhabetical order of the keys not numeral order of the values. They dont have a sense of order but they can be ordered as I showed on my first piece of code that worked, I understands why my second one doesnt work now, I'm just saying your solution is not the best

Comment: @Fargo this has nothing to do with `zip(..)` or `Stocks.items()`. Both will return the exact same output which is a list of tuples of the form `[(key_1, value_1), (key_2, value_2), ...]` (in an arbitrary order).

Comment: @DeepPurple Yes both will result in a list of tuples but this is the difference:
`([('APPL', 99), ('FB', 76), ('AMZN', 306), ('YHOO', 39), ('GOOG', 520)])`
`([(99, 'APPL'), (76, 'FB'), (306, 'AMZN'), (39, 'YHOO'), (520, 'GOOG')])`
The first one uses `Stocks.items()` the second one uses `zip = (Stock.values(), Stock.keys())`, so the second one allows
me to use Sorted, Max and Min on the values wich are numbers, and the first one, `Stock.items()` does not.

Comment: @Fargo I see. I missed the fact that you actually used `zip(Stocks.values(), Stocks.keys())` and not `zip(Stocks.keys(), Stocks.values())`.